# SQL Запрос для вывода пользователей с аккаунта которых больше 2х регистраций по IP

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Приветствую!
Есть такая схема данных:

```
create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "surname"
  t.integer  "group_id"
  t.datetime "birthday"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "ip_address"
  t.integer  "supervisor_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end

create_table "supervisors", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.text   "characheristic"
end
```

необходимо написать запрос(можно средствами Active Record) чтобы вывести
всех людей, c IP которых произошло более одной регистрации, и при этом хотя бы у одного из них должна быть написана характеристика научного руководителя.

также пытался вынести IpAddress в отдельную модель и уже

```
class IpAddress
  has_many :students
end
class Students
  belongs_to :ip_address
 end
```

но тоже не смог составить запрос(

PostgreSQL, Ruby on Rails

Comment: Покажите ваши запросы, тогда можно будет сказать что в них не так.

Comment: select * from students where (select count(*) from "students" group by "students"."ip_address") > 2;  @ВладимирМартьянов

Answer (score 1):

Если наличие характеристики - это not null supervisor_id, то

```sql
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ip_address IN 
(
    SELECT ip_address FROM Students 
    INNER JOIN Supervisors on Students.supervisor_id = Supervisors.supervisor_id
    GROUP BY ip_address 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND MAX(characheristic) IS NOT NULL
)
```

<sup>проверял на ms sql, но синтаксис тот же</sup>

Comment: наличие характеристики это не supervisor_id, supervisor.characteristic может быть null

Comment: @Xiting ну тогда его и проверяйте. подправил.